# Python web scraper won't save image files

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, io, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I started working on a small image scraping terminal program that is supposed to save images to a specified file within the program hierarchy. This comes from a basic tutorial I found online. However, whenever I enter in a search term into the terminal to start scraping bing.com (yeah, i know), the program crashes. The errors i get seem to focus on either the image file type not being recognized or the file path where the images will be saved is not being recognized:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    print("Getting", item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)
```

Error thrown: Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './scraped_images/3849747391_4a7dc3f19e_b.jpg'

I've tried adding a file path variable (using pathlib) and concatenating that with with the other necessary variables:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path

image_folder = Path("./scraped_images/")
search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    print("Getting", item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    img.save(image_folder + title, img.format)
```

Error thrown: Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

I've checked the documentation for PIL, BeautifulSoup, etc. to see if any updates may have been screwing me up, i've checked the elements on bing to see if the classes are correct, and even tried searching by different class and nothing worked. I'm at a loss. Any thoughts or guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pathlib import Path
import os
image_folder = Path("./scraped_images/")
if not os.path.isdir(image_folder):
    print('Making %s'%(image_folder))
    os.mkdir(image_folder)
search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    print("Getting", item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    if img_obj.ok:
        with open('%s/%s'%(image_folder, title), 'wb') as file:
            file.write(img_obj.content)
```

You can use PIL but in this case you do not need it.

I also improved the code with PIL to work better:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path

s = requests.Session()
image_folder = Path("./scraped_images/")
search = input("Search for:")
params = {"q": search}
r = s.get("http://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
    try:
        img_obj = s.get(item.attrs["href"], headers={'User-Agent': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0'})
        if img_obj.ok:
            print("Getting", item.attrs["href"])
            title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
            if '?' in title:
                title = title.split('?')[0]
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
            img.save(str(image_folder) + '/' + title, img.format)
        else:
            continue
    except OSError:
        print('\nError downloading %s try to visit'
              '\n%s\n'
              'manually and try to get the image manually.\n' %(title, item.attrs["href"]))
```

I use a requests session and added try and except if PIL can't make the image. I also only make try to make a image if the request get a 200 response from the site.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, that seems to work a lot better. Thanks for the assistance!